# Index sections from plist

Tags: ios

I have a plist that I am trying to sort into sections. I have everything setup and it is working but the one thing I cannot setup is the `numberOfRowsInSection` count. At the moment it displays the first section only `'b'` as shown in the image.

The issue I am having is that I am using plist to populate the table but cannot figure out the section count as below. Also need to sort the table alphabetically.

```
 // Find out the path of recipes.plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"laws" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    //Load Data into Array
    self.tableData = [dict objectForKey:@"Laws"];
    self.tableIndexData = [dict objectForKey:@"index"]; //containing the index

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      // NSString *sectionTitle = [self.tableIndexData objectAtIndex:section];
      // NSArray *sectionAnimals = [self.tableData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        return [self.tableData count];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi section tables are typically **arrays within arrays, or arrays within an array of dictionaries.** its hard to see if this is the case in your code because the structure of your object keyed by @"Law" is not apparent from the code you showed. (It will be a lot easier for people to help you if you display the data as it is stored in the plist).

From your code object @"Laws" seems to be an array (1 level rather than an array of arrays or a dictionary with a nested array. Your code betrays the structure :

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection (NSInteger)section
{
     // NSString *sectionTitle = [self.tableIndexData objectAtIndex:section];
    // NSArray *sectionAnimals = [self.tableData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
       return [self.tableData count];
 }
```

What you need to do is 1st of all to have the correct structure (**nested arrays or arrays of dictionaries with nested array**)

once you have that structure,  the code for tableviewNumberOfRowsInSection should be something like this for an array of dictionaries with nested arrays:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return ([font_family_array count]);

}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [font_family_array objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"array"];
   NSInteger count = [array count];

   return (count);

}
```

Then to set the section header should be the following:

```
   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  NSDictionary *dict = [font_family_array objectAtIndex:section];
  NSString *title1 = [dict objectForKey:@"family"];
  return (title1);
}
```

In the example below font_family_array is an array of dictionaries with 2 elements
@family contains the header/ title and @array contains the nested array or the contents.  As mentioned  an array of arrays is also possible,